# Усреднение произведения в функции

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Имеется функция подобия, необходимо усреднить каждые 1000 значений х1, х2 и их разницы.
[image: Функция подобия]
Как это лучше всего сделать прямо в функции? Пробовал с помощью reshape, и теперь попробовал с помощью consolve, но такое ощущение, что усреднение работает не так( получаются все те же 1000000 значений в конце, однако график изменяется). Так вот как это лучше всего сделать и как в принципе можно усреднить разницу между двумя значениями((x2[100:]-x1[:999900])**2))?

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import numpy
from matplotlib import *
from scipy import *
from pylab import figure, show, setp
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



#We define a function which is going to be the recursive function.
def num_rossler(x1_n, y1_n, z1_n, x2_n, y2_n, z2_n, h, a, b, c, k, w1, w2):
    x1_n1=x1_n+h*(-w1*y1_n-z1_n+K*(x2_n-x1_n)) # dx/dt = x1 + h*( - y1 - z1 + k (x2 - x1 ))
    y1_n1=y1_n+h*(w1*x1_n+a*y1_n)
    z1_n1=z1_n+h*(b+z1_n*(x1_n-c))   
 
    x2_n1=x2_n+h*(-w2*y2_n-z2_n+K*(x1_n-x2_n))
    y2_n1=y2_n+h*(w2*x2_n+a*y2_n)
    z2_n1=z2_n+h*(b+z2_n*(x2_n-c))
    return x1_n1, y1_n1, z1_n1, x2_n1, y2_n1, z2_n1

def window(size):
    return np.ones(size)/float(size)

def simi_func(x1,x2):
    
    s=(((x2[100:]-x1[:999900])**2)/((np.convolve(x1,window(1000))[:999900]**2*np.convolve(x2,window(1000))[:999900]**2)**(1/2)))**(1/2)
    return s


#Now we prepare some variables
#First the parameters
a=0.165
b=0.2
c=10
K=0.2
w1=0.99
w2=0.95
 
#Them the time interval and the step size
t_ini=0
t_fin=10000
h=0.01
numsteps=int((t_fin-t_ini)/h)
 
#using this parameters we build the time.
t=numpy.linspace(t_ini,t_fin,numsteps)
#And the vectors for the solutions
x1=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
y1=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
z1=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
 
x2=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
y2=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
z2=numpy.zeros(numsteps)
s=numpy.zeros(numsteps)

ty=np.arange(0.00,2,0.0001)
 
#We set the initial conditions
x1[0]=0.001
y1[0]=0.001
z1[0]=0.001
 
x2[0]=0.002
y2[0]=0.002
z2[0]=0.002

n=x1.size-1
 
#This is the main loop where we use the recursive system to obtain the solution

for k in range(0, n):
    #We use the previous point to generate the new point using the recursion
    x1[k+1],y1[k+1],z1[k+1],x2[k+1],y2[k+1],z2[k+1]=num_rossler(x1[k],y1[k],z1[k],x2[k],y2[k],z2[k],t[k+1]-t[k],a,b,c,K,w1,w2)

#Now that we have the solution in vectors t,x,y,z is time to plot them.
s=simi_func(x1,x2)
print(size(s))
print(size(x1))
print(size(x2))
    
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1[100:20000]/0.01,s[:19900])
plt.xlim(0.001,2)
plt.ylim(0.00,3)
plt.show()


[ 1.00000000e-03  9.82099982e-04  9.45039281e-04  8.90721282e-04
  8.20861098e-04  7.37004405e-04  6.40544392e-04  5.32737015e-04
  4.14714727e-04  2.87498825e-04  1.52010572e-04  9.08119790e-06
 -1.40539094e-04 -2.96173026e-04 -4.57208952e-04 -6.23094294e-04
 -7.93329638e-04 -9.67463414e-04 -1.14508712e-03 -1.32583099e-03]>>[7.47e-04 5.2249987e-04 2.1100256e-04 9.7096109e-04] (пример для массива х1 и х2, считаем среднее между каждыми 5 значениями)
```

[ 1.00000000e-03  9.82099982e-04  9.45039281e-04  8.90721282e-04
8.20861098e-04  7.37004405e-04  6.40544392e-04  5.32737015e-04
4.14714727e-04  2.87498825e-04  ]
[ 2.00000000e-03  1.95899996e-03  1.89983383e-03  1.82430268e-03
1.73402951e-03  1.63047706e-03  1.51496388e-03  1.38867868e-03
1.25269341e-03  1.10797483e-03  ]>>>(считаем разницу между х1(первый массив) и х2(второй массив)
[1e-03 7.5e-04 7.56e-04 7.08e-04
6.5e-04 5.8e-04 4.9e-04 3.9e-04
2.9e-04 1.77e-04 ] >>>(считаем среднее между каждыми 5 значениями)
[7.728e-04 3.854e-04]

x2[100:]-x1[:999900]**2 необходимо усреднить*

---

Требуется повторить графики из статьи о [согласованном колебании двух связанных аттракторов](http://www.stat.physik.uni-potsdam.de/%7Epikovsky/pdffiles/1997/prl_78_4193.pdf).

[image: График функции подобия]
[image: Зависимость x2 от x1]

Comment: "усреднить каждые 1000 значений х1, х2 и их разницы" не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду

Comment: В строчке s=(..) в знаменателе x2[100:]-x1[:999900] и эту разницу необходимо усреднить. Сейчас добавлю картинку уравнения в вопрос, чтобы понятнее было.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшой  (10-15 строк) пример входных данных, "усредните" вручную каждые 2-3 значения и покажите датасет, который вы хотите получить. В текущей формулировке не очень понятно что и как вы хотите сделать...

Comment: Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Так понятнее что необходимо?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Посмотрел на статью, и до меня дошло, что они хотят. `S` - это не корреляционная функция со скользящим средним, а зависимость корреляционного коэффициента от параметра сдвига `tau`. То есть всё же берём функцию `S(x1,x2, skew)` и считаем, как изменится корреляция по мере изменения `skew`.

Сначала у меня не получилось построить нужные графики, потому что я сдвигал `x1`. Казалось бы, какая разница, система симметричная. Оказывается, сдвигать нужно `x2`, именно `x2` запаздывает относительно `x1`:  `S(x2,x1, skew)`.

После этой замены корреляция стала считаться так же, как у авторов статьи.

На базе "записной книжки", сделанной для вашего предыдущего вопроса я сделал [новую, в которую добавил вычисление функции похожести](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/python/1271078/correlation.ipynb)

Картинки "как из статьи" в конце notebook-а.

---

В вашей функции `simi_func` я не увидел собственно усреднения. В том, как вы её вычисляете, получаются исключительно поэлементные операции. То есть вычисляется функция двух аргументов `t` и `tau`:
[image: S(t,tau) без усреднения]

Вам нужно добавить в `simi_func` усреднение в соответствии с вашей формулой. Что-то вроде такого:

```
def S(x1,x2, skew=100):
    # защита от дурака
    assert(len(x1) == len(x2))
    
    # смещённая разность x1 и x2
    diff_skew = x1[skew:] - x2[:-skew]
    # средний квадрат смещённой разности
    divident = np.average(diff_skew*diff_skew)
    
    # средний квадрат x1
    x1_square = np.average(x1*x1)
    # средний квадрат x2
    x2_square = np.average(x2*x2)
    divisor = np.sqrt(x1_square*x2_square)
    
    return divident/divisor
```

Результат `S(x1,x2)` равен `1.3918739301634857`

**UPDATE**

Функция `S` выше вычисляет коэффициент корреляции. Судя по комментарию, нужна корреляционная функция, которая вычисляет такой коэффициент не по всему массиву значений, а в пределах некоторого окна.

Делаем практически то же самое, только вместо среднего используем скользящее среднее. Встроенной функции в `numpy`, похоже, нет, поэтому вот моя версия. По мотивам [подсмотренного в интернете](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27681394/9047589)

```
# Возвращается массив result[i] = sum(x[i:i+size])
def runsum(x, size):
    x_cumsum = np.zeros(len(x)+1)
    x_cumsum[1:] = np.cumsum(x)
    x_runsum = x_cumsum[size:] - x_cumsum[:-size]
    return x_runsum

# возвращается массив result[i] = sum(x[i:i+size])/size
def runavg(x, size):
    return runsum(x, size) / size
```

Дальше действуем так же как для вычисления коэффициента корреляции:

```
def corrFn(x1,x2, delta_t=100, range_t=1000):
    # (x1(t+dt) - x2(t))^2
    diff_skew = x1[delta_t:] - x2[:-delta_t]
    diff_skew_square = diff_skew*diff_skew
    
    x1_square = x1[:-delta_t]*x1[:-delta_t]
    x2_square = x2[:-delta_t]*x2[:-delta_t]
    
    diff_skew_square_mean = runavg(diff_skew_square, range_t)
    x1_square_mean = runavg(x1_square, range_t)
    x2_square_mean = runavg(x2_square, range_t)
    
    return diff_skew_square_mean/np.sqrt(x1_square_mean*x2_square_mean)
```

Получится массив длиной `len(x1) - range_t - delta_1 + 1`, содержит корреляцию для каждого момента времени.

Если вам нужны только значения с интервалом 1000, то `corrFn(x1,x2, 100, 1000)[::1000]` даст вам массив, состоящий из каждого тысячного значения массива, который вычислит функция корреляции.

**UPDATE 2**

Как найти величину сдвига, соответствующую наилучшей корреляции.

```
tau = np.arange(0,30,dt)
S = np.array([ simFn(x2, x1, int(_tau/dt)) for _tau in tau ])
# Минимум S на первых 10 секундах
min_idx = np.argmin(S[:1000])

# tau[min_idx] - момент времени, когда достигнут минимум S, 
# np.min - соответствующее значение
tau[min_idx], np.min(S[:1000])
```

В массиве `S` значения коэффициента корреляции как функции от величины сдвига `tau`. `np.argmin` находит номер элемента массива с наименьшим значением, `np.min` возвращает само значение.

Для того, чтобы пересчитать номер минимального элемента в фактическое значение достаточно просто взять элемент тау по этому индексу: `tau[min_idx]`

В [notebook-е](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/python/1271078/correlation.ipynb) эти значения вычисляются в ячейках 14 и 21.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, можно сделать примерно так, но в таком случае значение s-одно, и построить график s(Tay(смещение)) не получается. То есть задумка была в том, чтобы посчитать хотя бы 100 точек.

Comment: @HUR1EY, я добавил вычисление корреляционной функции со скользящим средним.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, вроде бы все логично и правильно, но полученные графики все же отличаются от литературных. Буду дальше пробовать разобраться и получить то что надо.

Comment: @HUR1EY, покажите ожидаемый график. Ну и если книга содержит метод вычисления среднего, то и им тоже поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос ожидаемые графики и в самом низу ссылка на google drive с литературой в pdf-файле.

Comment: @HUR1EY, я таки получил нужные картинки. Ссылка на jupyter notebook в начале ответа.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Извините, как я понял, Вы разбираетесь в этой теме. Не могли бы Вы подсказать, как тут определяется минимум функции корреляции?(Сигма, по которой мы потом строим картинку 1(2)) @Pak Uula

Comment: @HUR1EY я добавил UPDATE 2 в ответ и обновил "записную книжку" в git

Comment: получилось, спасибо) @Pak Uula